# How to get access to text from all the textboxes( where textboxes are created dynamically) in windows phone runtime

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have been trying to get texts from the collection of textboxes which are created dynamically by binding a collection to a stackpanel using items control which is in seperate user control which i am loading on a page in windows phone runtime.

Below is the code of my UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="CfMobility.UserControls.CredentialsUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CfMobility.UserControls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedCategorySettings}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel IsTapEnabled="False">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SettingKey}" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox  Text="{Binding SettingValue}" Width="300px"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

I have a Content control in another page as below:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="Container" Grid.Row="1" Margin="19,10,19,0">
        </ContentControl>
```

Where i am binding this content control to above stackpanel when i am navigating to the page.

As You can see i had bonded "SelectedCategorySettings" collection to StackPanel using ItemsScroll which displays number of text boxes based on the collecion. Here i am unable to figure out if i want to save text from all the text boxes which are displayed on the page into a json file, how to access the text of all the text boxes which are dynamically displayed in above scenario?

PS: note that items is control is in a separate user control.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use ObservableCollection for SelectedCategorySettings and your model class which contains SettingKey and SettingValue should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface as in following example code. If you do it correctly then whatever the changes happen in UI (in your case, text changes of textbox) will automatically reflect in your model objects in the ObservableCollection. If you are interested to learn more about how this works, I recommend you to search about mvvm design pattern in Windows Phone development.

```
public class Setting : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _settingKey;

    public string SettingKey
    {
        get { return _settingKey; }
        set { 
            _settingKey = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SettingKey");
        }
    }

    private string _settingValue;

    public string SettingValue
    {
        get { return _settingValue; }
        set {
            _settingValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SettingValue");
        }
    }


    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this !! But my problem is accessing all the text boxes content at once to save in some file in local storage. As you can see above "SettingValue" TextBox. Suppose i already have some values in "SelectedCategorySettings" which means it will have many textboxes on the page. Now, suppose that i have edited some of these textboxes and want to save them back to some file say,JSON in local storage. As these textboxes are created dynamically, i want to access the content to save into a file. How can i do it?

Comment: Yes, I understood your problem. But the problem is you are trying to access textboxes which created by ItemsControl as just like a textbox created with xaml by name or something like that. But this is not the way you do it in windows phone. You need to use mvvm pattern just like I explained in above answer. If you do it correctly values in "SelectedCategorySettings" will automatically update by ui when user type and change values in textboxes. Then you can get new values from "SelectedCategorySettings" itself. So you don't need explicitly access textboxes to get new values.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a method like this:

```
var textBoxes = AllTextBoxes(this);

public List<TextBox> AllTextBoxes(DependencyObject parent)
{
    var list = new List<TextBox>();
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is TextBox)
        {
            list.Add(child as Control);
            continue;
        }
        list.AddRange(AllChildren(child));
    }
    return list;
}
```